# escape and replace part of an xml attribute in scala

Tags: xml, scala, escaping

I have an xml file in which I want to modify parts of several of the attributes.  In scala, it is entirely possible to replace the entire attribute very easily.  Replacing part of an attribute is proving to be more difficult.  I'm curious if anyone has any ideas.  Here is an example:

```
<Server name="my-{siteCode}-srv01">
    <User name="root">
        <FileToGet path="whatever" />
        <FileToGet path="whatever2" />
    </User>
</Server>
<Server name="my-{siteCode}-srv02">
    <User name="root">
        <FileToGet path="whatever" />
        <FileToGet path="whatever2" />
    </User>
</Server>
```

I'd really like to be able to just replace {siteCode} with a site code and be done with it.  Scala doesn't seem to have a way to do that within the attribute though.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone else that might want to do this, my unfortunate hack is to give the {siteCode} variable a goofy enough wildcard value that I can just do a String replace on it.  It works fine for my uses, but it's not a good solution.